# Plugin development - How to access actions?

Tags: ajax

I have a simple controller in /craft/plugins/craft-dns-notifier/src/conrollers/DnsNotifierController:

```
namespace kokesjan\dnsnotifier\controllers;
use craft\web\Controller;

class DnsNotifierController_DbController extends Controller
{
    public function buu() {
        echo "tradada";
    }
}
```

I would like to access the buu() action from src/templates/index.html twig file via Ajax.

I've had no luck for three days, unable to find any hint anywhere. Nothing I have tried worked. It seems like very easy task to me, but I just can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest generating the code via [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/) and if you have code comments enabled, it'll give you the URI that you need to trigger your action in the example code.

But essentially it's going to be a kebab-case version of your controller route, with a kebab-case version of your method name (but removing the action preface).

For you, first you should rename your method thusly:

```php
    public function actionBuu() {
        echo "tradada";
    }
```

And then your URI would be something like:

```
/actions/dns-notifier/dns-notifier-controller-db-controller/buu
```

See here for more on [controller actions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers)